# Stronger norm for continuous functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

On $C[a,b]$ I want to show that $\|f\|_1 = \displaystyle \max_{a\leq t\leq b} |f(t)|$ is stroner than $\|f\|_2=\left(\int_a^b |f(t)|^2 dt\right)^{1/2}$

What I have done is as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_2^2 =& \int_a^b |f(t)|^2 dt\\
\leq& \int_a^b \left(\displaystyle\max_{a\leq t\leq b} |f(t)|\right)^2 dt\\
=& \left(\displaystyle\max_{a\leq t\leq b} |f(t)|\right)^2\int_a^b 1\,dt\\
=&\|f\|_1^2(b-a)\\
\implies&\|f\|_2\leq \sqrt{b-a}\|f\|_1
\end{align*}
$$
Now the result follows if $\sqrt{b-a}\gt0$, but what if $b=a$, for stronger I need a positive number, $C\gt 0$ such that $\|f\|_2 \leq C\|f\|_1$

Comment: $\|f\|_2$ is not even a norm if $b=a$.

Comment: @JohnMa So in that case I can say that $a<b$ and I am done, thanks!

Comment: If you have $\|f\|_2 \le 0 \, \|f\|_1$ in case $a = b$, you automatically have $\|f\|_2 \le 42 \, \|f\|_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Ma has stated that $\|f\|_2$ is not a norm if $b=a$ and therefore it follows that $a\lt b$, it also therefore follows that $\sqrt{b-a}\gt0$. This gives us the result.